# MacOS two-finger scroll is sometimes interpreted as a single-click

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, apple-silicon

I haven't seen anyone report this problem, and I suppose it could attributable to my clumsiness, but I've been seeing the following behavior, and I wonder if there are any fixes.

Hardware: Apple MacBook Air, M1.
OS: 11.2.2
Trackpad preferences are set to include nearly all gestures, including 2-fingers for secondary click. Scroll direction is natural.

What happens is that as I'm two-finger scrolling through a web-based article (news, for example), I'll put my fingers on the pad to scroll, and if I'm hovering over a hyperlink at the time, the machine will often interpret my action as a single-click and follow the link.

I have to assume that there's some sort of lowpass filtering or time delay so that the two fingers don't need to touch the trackpad at *exactly* the same time to be interpreted as a two-finger event. I wonder if the timer is adjustable.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have tap to click on based on your description of the settings?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the delay; I hadn't noticed a response.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you - unfortunately. My guess is that you're simply touching one finger sooner than the other. As someone who doesn't use tap to click there's nothing more I can offer (hence not putting this in as an answer or anything)

Comment: Yeah, I know. Thanks for the feedback. I think the algorithm is a bit touchy.

Comment: @Tom I was wondering whether you have adapted to the trackpad by now? I recently replaced my 2014 Macbook Pro with an M1 Macbook Pro, and I'm having some issues with the new trackpad; double tap often fails to register if tap-drag is enabled, and two-finger scrolling occasionally doesn't work (not yet sure whether it's registering a click instead). I'll try a colleague's M1 Macbook Pro to make sure I don't have a faulty trackpad.